# How user gets automatically logged in on different server domain web application when they are sharing same authentication system like oAuth 2

Tags: angularjs, django, python-3.x, oauth-2.0

**Situation** :

1. I have an Authentication system developed in django python 0Auth2.
2. I have 3 angular web application with different server domain which use same authentication system for user login or signup.

   **For eg**: 'webapp1', 'webapp2', 'webapp3'.

**Want To Do :**

If user xyz login webapp1 and open webapp2 in a new tab of the same browser then user xyz should be logged in automatically on webapp2 and same for webapp3.

**Question** :

How user gets automatically logged in on different server domain web applications when they are sharing the same authentication system like oAuth 2 designed in django python?

Comment: I don't think its possible like that. Look At StackOverflow and the whole StackExchange Gang. When you are switching sites you have to sign in separately for each site. Even though you share the same Base account you need to sign up an log in at each page. I think there is a reason why they don't do it another way.

Comment: @hansTheFranz that's not exactly true. You might want to read [this answer on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64274). Hrushi Shinde I think you'll find it useful too, additionally [this blog post](http://merbist.com/2012/04/04/building-and-implementing-a-single-sign-on-solution/) might be interesting (disclaimer: I am not in any way connected with its author). After reading the above mentioned you might want to reconsider your question, as I think in its present form it's too broad.

Comment: @rafalmp I was not sure, thats why I wrote a comment and used the word "think" but good pointing that out.I will check the link. Thanks for clearing the issue